# heuristic to find pairwises in a correlation matrix above a threashold

Tags: python, algorithm, distance-matrix

I have **N** vectors **v** of size **m**. I can compute a correlation between two vectors like this :

```
d = correlation(v1,v2)
```

I would like to find for each vector v1 a pair vector v2 where correlation value is above 0.9. 
I cannot compute the correlation matrix because I have a huge amount of vectors ( N > 3 millions ).
The naive algorithm looks like this :

```py
for v1 in vectors: 
  for v2 in vectors:
     if correlation(v1,v2) > 0.9:
        yield (v1,v2)
        break
```

Do you have better algorithm to suggest ? I think I can do it using a heuristic algorithm because I don't want the maximum correlation value but just one among others where the correlation is among the threshold.

Comment: First off correlation is symettric so you can half your iterations but ensuring the v1_index > v2_index. What's the end goal? Do you need to find all the pairs that lie above 0.9? Or if you are going for an approximation, have you thought about what metrics would suffice (maybe in terms of precision / recall)? You might be able to build some sort of heuristic / memoized approach by making an [assumption of transitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181380/40604).

Comment: How do you compute the correlation? What data types are your vectors? Are you using any external packages?

Comment: I just want to find one mate per vectors. Not all : ( v1, vx), ( v2, vy) , (v3, vz) ...
My vectors are integers : v1 = {1,5,6,4,2,5... } . 
I m using correlation distance from scipy.cdist or from pandas.Series.corr() or my custom

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of **m**?

Comment: I can have m = 3 millions of vectors. Each vectors correspond to a position along the human genome.